# Checkbox Unchecked on Refresh Page

Tags: wordpress, checkbox

I know this is a very simple question but this has ruined a day. Actually, in wp-admin I have created checkboxes for the user to check, The user can these boxes but that becomes uncheck on the refresh page although the user has checked them.

I want to remain checked on the refresh page. Anyone can guide me?

```
<?php global $wpdb;
    $res = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM wp_posts WHERE post_status='publish' AND post_type='page'",ARRAY_A); 
?>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>
                //Post Title
            </th>
            <th>
                //Permission
            </th>
        </tr>
        <?php
            if( $res ) {
                foreach ( $res as $values ) {
        ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo  $values['post_title']; ?></td>
            <td><input type='checkbox' name='Accessable_Pages[]' autocomplete="off" value=<?php echo $values['ID']; ?>  ><br></td>
        </tr>
        <?php } ?>
```

Comment: Simply use <input type="checkbox" checked> if you want to have it checked from the start or even after refresh.

Comment: @Senpai.D he said he wants to user himself to check this box, so he can use checked.

Comment: you will need to add this action to the database, so when the user check the box, the database get updated with the new action.

other way is to set a cookie, setting a cookie will keep it checked even if the user refresh the page